# How would you block a specific user from a specific IP and a specific port?

Tags: iptables, firewall, hosts.deny

Just curious here, no real use case...

The answer is probably /etc/hosts.deny but asking in case there are other way to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [netfilter "owner"](https://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables-extensions.man.html) module/extension to create the appropriate rules to match traffic from a specific user (on the Linux system where the user resides).

```
sudo iptables -I OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner <USERNAME> -p tcp -m tcp -d destination-address --dport destination-port-number -j REJECT
```

But once the IP traffic leaves the system there is no concept of "username/owner" in TCP/IP traffic anymore, packets only contain protocol, IP-address and port numbers and have no user identification that you could use as a reliable basis for firewall rules on a remote system or in an intermediate firewall.

The historic solution for that was the [`ident`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ident_protocol) protocol and `identd` service (RFC 931 and descendant [RFC 1413](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1413)) running on the source IP-address of an incoming connection, which would return a username associated with a particular TCP connection. That is what allowed username based authentication in  the [`hosts.[allow|deny]`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/hosts_access) access controls.
I don't know of anyone that either still supports or trusts the ident service anymore and even the RFC is quite explicit in section 6 on the security considerations *"The Identification Protocol is not intended as an authorization or
access control protocol"*, so don't go there.

Comment: "Don't go there" - sold. Thank you for your insights

Answer (score 1):

you could install the UFW (Uncomplicated Firewall) package and then use the UFW in order to create some entries. When activating UFW all incoming traffic is being blocked & outgoing traffic is allowed by default. Before activating the UFW make sure to whitelist SSH connections in order to prevent locking you out from your server with `sudo ufw allow 22`. To enable your firewall you can use `sudo ufw enable`. To reload the firewall configurations you can enter `sudo ufw reload`.

In order to block a specific IPv4/6 Address you can create a ufw entry with this command:
`sudo ufw deny from [IPv4-Address] to any` to block an IPv4 Address from your entire server.

But I dont exactly know about blocking a specifiy IPv4 Addresses & Port with UFW.

Comment: Indeed, Ufw and Firewalld seem to be possible solutions too. Thank you

Comment: No problem :) Happy to help